# Recycler view off screen child view holder returning null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, expandablerecyclerview

I have 20 child views in `recyclerView`, on launch only 5 are visible.
If I try access the off screen child view holder, `null` is returned. How to solve this issue?

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
```

`holder` is `null`.

Comment: and it should be `null` - the docs say: *"This method checks only the children of RecyclerView. If the item at the given position is not laid out, it will not create a new one."*

Answer (score 1):

It should be null, See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView)

> Recycle (view): A view previously used to display data for a specific
> adapter position may be placed in a cache for later reuse to display
> the same type of data again later. This can drastically improve
> performance by skipping initial layout inflation or construction.

So, you can see, the views which are not on screen will not be generated, and thus the
method **recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);** will return null.

Answer (score 0):

if you really in need to access the item on the off screen you can try this code of mine:

```
for(int i = 0; i<Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.getAdapter()).getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) != null) {
            View childView = Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i)).itemView;
            ImageView childCheckThumb = childView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_check);
            TextView namePlateView = childView.findViewById(R.id.name_plate_text_view);
            childCheckThumb.setVisibility(thumb);
        }
    }
```

in my case I'm accessing to make all the off screen list become checked, hope this can solve your problem